# Delphi iOS IPv6 trouble. Please ensure that your app is compatible with IPv6 networks

Tags: ios, delphi, networking, indy

I can't to publish my iOS app to AppStore.

Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin, iOS64, Win 8.1.

I received the next info from apple:

> Thank you for your response.
>
> Please ensure that your app is compatible with IPv6 networks.
>
> The easiest way to test your app for IPv6 compatibility is to set up a local IPv6 network on your Mac. You can then connect to the network from your iOS devices to test IPv6 compatibility.
>
> Please follow the step-by-step instructions provided in Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks.
>
> For additional information about supporting IPv6 networks, please review Supporting IPv6-only Networks.

---

It's connection code.

```
     if (FSocket<>nil) then
     begin
          if not FSocket.Connected then
          begin
               SetState(mwtrstDisConnected);
               FSocket.Free;
               FSocket:=nil;
          end
          else
              exit;
     end;

     FSocket:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
     FSocket.Host:=FHost;
     FSocket.Port:=FPort;

//CheckCode


{$ifdef KBMMW_USING_INDY_9_OR_NEWER}
     FSocket.BoundPortMin:=FMinClientPort;
     FSocket.BoundPortMax:=FMaxClientPort;
{$endif}

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_10}
     FSocket.ReadTimeout:=RequestTimeout*1000;
     FSocket.ConnectTimeout:=ConnectTimeout*1000;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_8_00_23}
     FSocket.Connect;
{$ELSE}
 {$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_9}
     FSocket.Connect(ConnectTimeout*1000);
 {$ELSE}
     FSocket.Connect;
 {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
     DoConnected(Info);
```

In my opinion I have to insert the next code in //CheckCode place.

```
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
  IdURI := TIdURI.Create('195.34.x.x');
  try
    try
      ss := GStack.ResolveHost(IdURI.Host, TIdIPVersion.Id_IPv6);
      IdURI.IPVersion := TIdIPVersion.Id_IPv6;
    except
      IdURI.IPVersion := TIdIPVersion.Id_IPv4; // Just in case.
    end;

    //ShowMessage(ss);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdURI);
    TIdStack.DecUsage;
  end;
```

But this code (GStack.ResolveHost) doesn't work on iOS.

How to solve it?

Comment: "doesn't work on iOS" is not a helpful error description. How doesn't it work? Does it give you an error? Does it give you an unexpected result? Does it do nothing at all? Does your app crash? You need to be specific with things like this.

Comment: *In my opinion*, setting `Id.URI := TIdURI.Create('195.34.x.x');` is doomed to fail, because that's an IPv4 address, so it clearly can't resolve as IPv6. Is that what you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: Ken is right. It doesnt make sense to ask `ResolveHost()` (which does work on iOS) to resolve an IPv4 address using IPv6 lookups. Do note that Indy 10 can enumerate local assigned IPs and report if they are IPv4 or IPv6, so it is possible to detect if the device is connected to an IPv6 network vs an IPv4 network.

Comment: Is true, problem with {Id.URI := TIdURI.Create('195.34.x.x');} and {ResolveHost()} function.  And how to detect if the device is connected to an IPv6 and what the next (if connected) how to convert IPv4 address to IPv6? Could you show some works demo?

Comment: Why are you even using `TIdURI` at all? If you have an IP address to begin with, just assign it directly to the `Host` and set the `IPVersion` accordingly (there are several ways in Indy to detect if a string is an IPv4 or IPv6 address, such as the `TIdIPAddress` class). To convert an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address, you have to re-encode it as an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. Indy has no function for that, but it can be as simple as prepending `'::ffff:'` to the IPv4 address (`'195.34.x.x'` -> `'::ffff:195.34.x.x'`), but that is not going to solve your underlying problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```
FSocket := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
FSocket.Host := FHost;
FSocket.Port := FPort;

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_9_OR_NEWER}
FSocket.BoundPortMin := FMinClientPort;
FSocket.BoundPortMax := FMaxClientPort;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_10}
FSocket.ReadTimeout := RequestTimeout*1000;
FSocket.ConnectTimeout := ConnectTimeout*1000;

// check if connecting to an IPv4/IPv6 address directly...
if GStack.IsIP(FHost) then // only checks for IPv4 right now
begin
  FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  FSocket.Connect;
end
else if MakeCanonicalIPv6Address(FHost) <> '' then
begin
  FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
  FSocket.Connect;
end
else begin
  // connecting to a hostname, try IPv6 first, then fallback to IPv4...
  try
    FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
    FSocket.Connect;
  except
    FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
    FSocket.Connect;
  end;
end;
{$ELSE}
  // only IPv4 is supported...
  {$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_9}
FSocket.Connect(ConnectTimeout*1000);
  {$ELSE}
FSocket.Connect;
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}

DoConnected(Info);
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  LIPAddress: TIdIPAddress;
  LLocalIPs: TIdStackLocalAddressList;
  TryIPv4, TryIPv6: Boolean;
  I: Integer;

...

FSocket := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
FSocket.Host := FHost;
FSocket.Port := FPort;

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_9_OR_NEWER}
FSocket.BoundPortMin := FMinClientPort;
FSocket.BoundPortMax := FMaxClientPort;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_10}
FSocket.ReadTimeout := RequestTimeout*1000;
FSocket.ConnectTimeout := ConnectTimeout*1000;

LIPAddress := TIdIPAddress.MakeAddressObject(FHost);
if LIPAddress <> nil then
begin
  // connecting to an IPv4/IPv6 address...
  FSocket.IPVersion := LIPAddress.AddrType;
  LIPAddress.Free;
  FSocket.Connect;
end else
begin
  // connecting to a hostname...

  TryIPv4 := False;
  TryIPv6 := False;

  LLocalIPs := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
  try
    GStack.GetLocalAddressList(LLocalIPs);
    for I := 0 to LLocalIPs.Count-1 do
    begin
      case LLocalIPs[I].IPVersion of
        Id_IPv4: TryIPv4 := True;
        Id_IPv6: TryIPv6 := True;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;

  if TryIPv6 then
  begin
    try
      FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
      FSocket.Connect;
      TryIPv4 := False;
    except
      if not TryIPv4 then
        raise;
    end;
  end;

  if TryIPv4 then
  begin
    FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
    FSocket.Connect;
  end;

  if not (TryIPv4 or TryIPv6) then
    raise Exception.Create('Not connected to an IPv4 or IPv6 network');
end;
{$ELSE}
  // only IPv4 is supported...
  {$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_9}
FSocket.Connect(ConnectTimeout*1000);
  {$ELSE}
FSocket.Connect;
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}

DoConnected(Info);
```

Note that this situation would become much simpler to handle once Indy implements the following feature, but that is a ways off, I think:

[Support round-robin DNS (support connecting to IPv4/IPv6 hostnames)](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/63498)

Comment: Remy, many thanks for demo code and help. I made update and sent it to Apple and expect a conclusion.

Comment: Hmm. first version work but doesn't help me. From Apple -> "To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review." 

will do second version.

Comment: @Bum why not? What is the actual problem you are having? You have not provided any useful details at all. Just saying "`ResolveHost()` doesn't work" is not explaining anything. WHY is it not working? Are you getting an error? WHY specifically is Apple rejecting your app? And have you done what Apple told you to do? "*set up a local IPv6 network ... to test IPv6 compatibility*"

Comment: No errors. The program works through the Internet but the apple does not accept and I received a message: 
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad Air 2 and iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, your app produced an error message when we tried to scan the QR code.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

Comment: And I can't test it because my mac mini don't support NAT64/DNS64 option. I'm looking for other ways for test.

Comment: @Bum what exactly does the screenshot show? What does the error message say?

Comment: I use kbmmw lib. The apple company shows me a message 'Not Connected'. 

                                   

  kbmMWSimpleClient1.Disconnect;
  kbmMWTCPIPIndyClientTransport1.Host :=  '95.84.x.x';
        try
          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Connect;
          ServerConnect := true;

        except
          ShowMessage('Not Connected!');
        end;

Comment: @Bum: `95.84.x.x` is an **IPv4 address**, that is NOT GOING TO WORK on an IPv6-only network, so of course it would fail during Apple's testing. You need to use an **IPv6 address** instead (or a hostname that resolves via DNS to an IPv6 address), and also make sure you set `kbmMWSimpleClient1.IPVersion` accordingly so Indy knows whether to use an IPv4 or IPv6 socket. The examples I gave you earlier would handle that setup for you. Do you understand what an IP address actually is? And what the difference is between IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I didn't close my issue. A made a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399659/how-to-use-ipv6-protocol-in-delphi-program-for-ios).

Comment: There was no need to ask a new question, you could have just asked for clarification of the code I gave you here. In any case, had you assigned the IP addresses to the `FHost` variable, the `if` statements would have handled them for you. `FHost := '2a02:2168:xxxxxxx.63b1:6e81:399c';` ... `FHost := '192.168.1.100';` Hard-coding the IPs in the `else` block is wrong. You clearly don't seem to understand the difference between IP addresses and hostnames, or what the code I gave you is doing for you. Did you ever TRY the code I gave you before you started monkeying around with it?