# How to use IPv6 protocol in Delphi program for iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, ipv6

I try to use IPv6 protocol in my mobile program.

My server is located inside the LAN behind NAT.

On the server I use IP port 3000

I have organized Virtual Server / Port Forwarding from my router port 45500 to port 3000 of my server.

On the server, I ran the ipconfig command and got IpV6 address.

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2168:xxxxxxx.63b1:6e81:399c
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7c7b:xxxxxxxx399c%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::e23fxxxxxxxxxcccc%12
                                       192.168.1.1
```

Next, I made changes to the connection library kmbmw:

```
FSocket.Host := FHost;
FSocket.Port := FPort;

...

{$IFDEF KBMMW_USING_INDY_10}

// Changes
//ShowMessage('Indy 10');
FSocket.ReadTimeout:=RequestTimeout*1000;
FSocket.ConnectTimeout:=ConnectTimeout*1000;

if GStack.IsIP(FHost) then // only checks for IPv4 right now
begin
  FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  FSocket.Connect;
end
else if MakeCanonicalIPv6Address(FHost) <> '' then
begin
  FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
  FSocket.Connect;
end
else
begin
  // connecting to a hostname, try IPv6 first, then fallback to IPv4...
  try
    FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
    FSocket.Host := '2a02:2168:xxxxxxx.63b1:6e81:399c'; // My IpV6 from ipconfig
    FSocket.Port := 3000;
    FSocket.Connect;
  except
    FSocket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
    FSocket.Host := '95.84.x.x'; // My static ipv4
    FSocket.Port := 45500;
    FSocket.Connect;
  end;
end;

// Changes

{$ENDIF}
```

Are these the right steps?

Comment: Since your server is behind a NAT router, if your client is outside the NAT then you have to connect it to the hostname/IP of the router, not the server. If the client is on the same LAN as the server, the NAT is not a factor, just connect to the server hostname/IP directly.

Comment: You modified the code I gave you in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43262108/65863). There is no reason for your to hard-code the server IPs in the `else` block, you should have assigned the IPs to the `FHost` variable and let the `if` statements handle it for you.  `FHost := '2a02:2168:xxxxxxx.63b1:6e81:399c';` ... `FHost := '192.168.1.100';`

Comment: Ops. Thanks a lot! It works! I'll send my current version to Apple.

Comment: About FHost I misunderstand how to fill FHost without KBMMW lib. I call        kbmMWSimpleClient1.Disconnect;
kbmMWTCPIPIndyClientTransport1.Host := 'MyIPv6'  or 'MyIPv4' ?;
kbmMWSimpleClient1.Connect;

Comment: I know nothing about kbmMMW, but that assignment looks fine to me (assuming `kbmMWSimpleClient1` does not have its own `Host` property, and `kbmMWTCPIPIndyClientTransport1` is somehow linked to `kbmMWSimpleClient1`). I suggest you contact the kbmMMW author about problems you are having with the library.